# How to select odd child of dl element with css?

Tags: html, css

I try to set background to dd and dt elements that exist into dl element.I use this selector but don't work.Please advice.

CSS:

```
     dl.dl-horizontal dt:odd {
   background: rgba(45, 177, 227, 0.34);
}
```

Html:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HistoricalName)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HistoricalName)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InsertDate)
    </dt>

           <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocationX)
    </dt>

           <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VisitorEn)
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Did you try using `dl.dl-horizontal dt:nth-child(odd)` selector?

Comment: `dl.dl-horizontal dt:nth-of-type(odd)`. `nth-child(odd)` will not work because all the `dt` are odd numbered.

Comment: I use this but set  background of all elements

Comment: Harry  :Don't work

Comment: @programmer138200: You just commented on Nenad's answer that it solved. The one I gave is same as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:nth-of-type(odd)`

```css
dl.dl-horizontal dt:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
dl.dl-horizontal dt:nth-child(odd) {
   background: rgba(45, 177, 227, 0.34);
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
dl.dl-horizontal dt:odd {
       background: rgba(45, 177, 227, 0.34);
    }
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t9bcq46/)**